# Can I decrease Version Number in Managed Package?

Tags: managed-package, isv

We have developed a Managed Package. The version number started at 1.1 and has increased to the latest version: 2.33.

1. Can we change the next upload package to version 1.0?
2. Will there any problems in updating the orgs that already have the package 2.33 or other installed ?
3. Will there any problems in future uploads when overlaping version numbers that already exist?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to change the **Version Number** once you have started releasing your product. The platform takes care of this for you, the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=uploading_packages.htm&siteLang=en_US) (see step 5) describes the process between Beta and Release phases.

[image]

It does not allow you to change the version due to the potential conflicts you describe in your question. What is worth considering is decoupling the Version Number of your package from how you name your package and describe the release to your customers. Since the **Version Name** can be edited for each upload.

[image]